# How to wait forever for at least one byte using COMMTIMEOUTS?

Tags: windows, winapi, timeout, serial-port, readfile

How can I configure [COMMTIMEOUTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363190%28VS.85%29.aspx) to wait forever for at least one byte to be read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by wrapping the read in a while loop. If no bytes were read I repeated the operation.